# how to impute missing values on numpy array created by train_test_split from pandas.DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, cross-validation, scikit-learn

I'm working on the dataset with lots of NA values with sklearn and `pandas.DataFrame`. I implemented different imputation strategies for different columns of the dataFrame based column names. For example NAs predictor `'var1'` I impute with 0's and for `'var2'` with mean.

When I try to cross validate my model using `train_test_split` it returns me a `nparray` which does not have column names. How can I impute missing values in this nparray?

P.S. I do not impute missing values in the original data set before splitting on purpose so I keep test and validation sets separately.

Comment: I split my test/train sets this way:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147278/how-do-i-create-test-and-train-samples-from-one-dataframe-with-pandas  Maybe this can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just cast your `np.array` from `train_test_split` back into a `pandas.DataFrame` so you can carry out your same strategy. This is very common to what I do when dealing with pandas and scikit. For example,

```
 a = train_test_split
 new_df = pd.DataFrame(a)
```

Comment: I can do that but it does not preserve any column names from the original dataframe. Then I need to impute values by indexes which can be very painful and can be a source of errors.

Comment: You can simply get the columns from the first dataframe in 
cols = list(df_orig.columns.values)
and then set the new column names with this
new_df = pf.DataFrame(a,columns=cols)

Answer (score 0):

From the link you mentioned in the comment, the train and test sets should be in the form of a  dataframe if you followed the first explanation.

In that case, you could do something like this:

```
df[variable] = df[variable].fillna(df[variable].median())
```

You have options on what to fill the N/A values with, check out the link.
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html

If you followed the second explanation, using sklearn's cross-validation, you could implement  mike1886's suggestion of transforming the arrays into dataframes and then use the fillna option.

Comment: the first suggestion will work but it is kind of "manual".I was looking for train_test_split way to get dataframe. The second explanation does what i normally do but it returns nparray to which it is hard to impute values since there are no column names.